# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, amazon-s3

> Access to Image at 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3bucket/1_1.png' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

This is the error message I'm getting. My code works in firefox, I'm guessing firefox doesn't care about cors but in other browsers I am getting this error. I tried various things and still can't get it to work. From what I read I am supposed to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' to the header, tried it and it didn't work, may have done it incorrectly, not sure. I also installed the cors package and tried using that with no luck.

amazon CORS configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var dbHost = 'mongodb://mlab info'


mongoose.connect(dbHost, { useNewUrlParser: true })

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + 'index.html');
}); 

//One of the things I tried
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,X-Requested-With');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  next();
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

console.log('Magic happens on port 3000');

exports = module.exports = app;
```

ang.js

```
var myapp = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ngMaterial','LocalStorageModule','ngGeolocation','md.data.table',]);
    myapp.config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
          }).
          when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashController'
          }).
          when('/kpi', {
            templateUrl: 'kpi.html',
            controller: 'kpiController'
          }).
          when('/kpiJobCreate', {
            templateUrl: 'kpiJobCreate.html',
            controller: 'bookController'
          }).
          when('/detail', {
            templateUrl: 'detail.html',
            controller: 'detailController'
          }).
          when('/book', {
            templateUrl: 'book.html',
            controller: 'bookController'
          }).
          when('/map', {
            templateUrl: 'map.html',
            controller: 'dashController'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
      }]);

      myapp.factory('userfactory', function(){
          userinfo = { };

          return {
              set: function(data){
                  userinfo = data;

              },
              get: function(){
                  return userinfo;
              }
          }
      });
```

dashboard.js //where I am trying to access the file. It's in a $compile template if that matters

```
myapp.controller("dashController", dashController);

    function dashController($scope, $http, $mdSidenav, $location, $mdDialog, $q, $timeout, $log, userfactory, localStorageService, $geolocation, $window, $compile) {

    s3.listObjects({ Prefix: featureType3 }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return alert('There was an error viewing the features: ' + err.message);
      }
      data.Contents.map(function (photo) {
        var photoKey = photo.Key;
        var photoUrl = href + encodeURIComponent(photoKey);

        var idxDot = photoKey.lastIndexOf("_") + 1;
        var extFile = photoKey.substr(idxDot, photoKey.length).toLowerCase();
        if (extFile == "1.png") {
          var htmlTemplate = $compile(
            '<li id="item3" class="ng-scope">' +
            '<img style="border: 3px solid black; width:85px; height:85px;" src="' + photoUrl + '"ng-click="addFeature(\'' + photoKey + '\');">' +
            '</li>')($scope) //I see the image here but it wont pass as into another function when I click on it called addFeature where I add it to a canvas
          angular.element(document.getElementById('app7')).append(htmlTemplate)
        } else { };
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: _"I'm guessing firefox doesn't care about cors"_  that is generally **not** the case

Comment: That error can only come from some JavaScript attempting to load `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3bucket/1_1.png` via AJAX (`fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest`). Since I cannot see anything in your code attempting to do so, I'd say you haven't provided enough information.

Comment: if it works in firefox, what is the issue? Which browser does it NOT work in?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: How about you just stick with one `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` for now. The docs specifically say you can only use one wildcard

Comment: It doesn't work in chrome, edge, opera, pretty much any other browser besides firefox

Comment: @Phil Oh yeah I was trying various things and forgot to remove that

Comment: @AndreS Any specific reason for ExposeHeader `<ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>`. You can run without it also

Comment: @front_end_dev I was following an amazon document before, you're right, I don't think I need it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with adding `"proxy": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"` on your package.json

or

adding attribute `crossOrigin="anonymous"` on tag img.
Ex : 
`<img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3bucket/1_1.png" crossOrigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Have you tried adding `CrossOrigin = "anonymous"` `img` tagged, like this 

`<img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3bucket/1_1.png" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: I swear it's the littlest things. So I had CrossOrigin = "anonymous" in my addFeature function but it was written a line ahead of where it should be. Moved it after my imageObj.src line and all works. Thank you so much and thank you to everyone that answered!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `app.all()` use `app.use()` And put it before `app.get`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,X-Requested-With');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  next();
});
```

Updated server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//One of the things I tried
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,X-Requested-With');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var dbHost = 'mongodb://mlab info'


mongoose.connect(dbHost, { useNewUrlParser: true })

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + 'index.html');
}); 



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

console.log('Magic happens on port 3000');

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I don't think changing the Express headers is going to enable CORS for an Amazon S3 bucket

Comment: Yes you are right. I din't see the image url is server from AWS S3. Well in that case he has to enable it there.

Comment: I tried this and the other comment without luck. I added my amazon CORS configuration